# Azure WebJob: Force stop if running longer than X mins

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs

I have python webjobs running on Azure. There are times when the script hangs because of which I need to force restart it so next iteration can pick it up.

How do I configure force stopping a webjob if running longer than 1 hour? Basically I want to mimic task scheduler's behavior.

My files on the webjob:

1. run.cmd

   D:\home\Python35\python.exe main.py
2. main.py

   just another python file
3. settings.job

   {"is_singleton":true}

At a given time, I want only 1 instance of the job running.

Edit (Answer): As a workaround, I changed continuous webjob to triggered one. And added this in app setting:

> WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 120

I'm printing something on the console every now and then. If no CPU activity is detected for 2 mins, the job will be aborted.

Answer (score 1):

You might want a second webjob that you can incorporate a healthcheck and restart the primary webjob if it detects no activity in your processes.

Another idea could be to use azure automation and have a powershell script that just restarts the webjob every hour.

Comment: could you tell me how do I detect inactivity in my processes?

Comment: I guess that would be determined by what your job is doing and if you could mine something like a last transaction time. There might be a way to look at the output of a webjob programatically but you'd have to check the APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement webjob restart by executing the `PowerShell` script regularly.

Please refer to the link:

1.[start webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/Start-AzureWebsiteJob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

2.[stop webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/Stop-AzureWebsiteJob?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

Actually, executing the `PowerShell` script is call [webjobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API).

You could find :

1.Start a continuous job

```
POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/start
```

2.Stop a continuous job

```
POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/stop
```

So,my suggestion is creating `another webjob` to control your `main webjob` restart by using the two methods above.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround. Could you tell me how do I monitor the running time in the powershell script? So in my webjob, I will have 3 steps: 1. POST call to start the job. 2. Monitor job runtime. 3. POST call to end the job if running longer than X hours. How do I do step 2 here?

Comment: @90abyss  What I think is that you could build a trigger webjob that executes every X hours, and this trigger webjobd close your main webjob then start it.

Comment: please check my edit. i may have found a workaround to resolve this without creating additional webjob